# how is it possible to make a clickable drawable?

Tags: android

I am newer in developing android app , can anybody tell me how is it possible to add an onClick listener to a drawable image? This is the code for putting the drawable images in the swapping mode but I want the user be able to go to another page by clicking on each of the drawable images. how can I add the onClick method to my code?

```
public class ViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.image_1,
        R.drawable.image_2,
        R.drawable.image_3,
        R.drawable.image_4
};
ViewAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
```

}

Comment: "how is it possible to add an onClick listener to a drawable image?" -- you don't. You put an`OnClickListener` on the widget that shows the drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `onClickListener` to the ImageView displaying the drawable:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
     imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // do something
         }
    });
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear Simon but can you please tell me where should I put it exactly because it shows an error on setOnClickListener!

Comment: Updated answer. Don't forget the import: `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: Thanks again but another problem , I want to show another intent(DetailActivity) by clicking on each image so how can I define this in the onClick method?

Comment: simply `startActivity(intent)` inside the `onClick()`

Comment: I used this if (arg0.getId() == R.id.agenda) {
                    //define a new Intent for the second Activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailDestinationActivity.class);
                    //start the second Activity
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                } but it says you should define startActivity(intent) !!!! so what is definition?